# How to make a custom list have sticky/floating headers

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online

I have a gigantic list with many columns that I put on my sharepoint site using the import excel app. I would love to be able to make it so that the column headings still show when you scroll down. I've seen custom codes out there on the internet for this. I'm pretty new to sharepoint, so the process of how and where to add the code is confusing to me. I don't know what type of web part to use and how to correctly use it to attach the HTML or whatever is needed. If someone could explain the process and possibly point me towards a solution, that would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using [Sticky Headers for SharePoint 2013](http://spoodoo.com/sticky-headers-sharepoint-2013-v2-0/). I would experiment with using it on just one page, list, or library to start with, and then if you like it, you can decide whether or not not to use it for your whole site. Below is how to do that.

**Download Script Files**

To use the Sticky Headers, first you need to download the `StickyHeaders_v2.9BETA.js` file from their [downloads page](http://spoodoo.com/downloads/). Then you'll also need to download [jQuery](https://jquery.com/). So the steps are to:

1. Download `StickyHeaders_v2.9BETA.js` file.
2. Download `jquery.min.js` file.

**Add the Script Files to a List Page**

1. Upload the scripts to your SharePoint site. Click on the gear icon in the top-right corner and then `Site Contents`. Upload the scripts you just downloaded into a document library, such as `Site Assets`. You can upload them to an existing library or create a new library.
2. Copy the location of the scripts you just upload to Notepad. Open up Notepad or another text editor (but not Word). Then go back to SharePoint and in the document library where you just uploaded the script files. In Internet Explorer, right-click on one of the file names and select `Copy shortcut` from the popup context menu. Paste this link in Notepad. Repeat the process for the other script file.
3. Go the page that has the long list and put the page in `Edit` mode. Click on the gear icon in the top-right corner and then `Edit page`.
4. Add a Script Editor Web Part to the page. In the Ribbon click the `Insert` tab then `Web Part` to open the Web Part panel. On the left column click the `Media and Content` category. In the middle column click `Script Editor`. [(Here are some instructions for how to do this with screenshots)](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2013/05/20/how-to-use-script-editor-web-part-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx)
5. Add your script references to the Script Editor Web Part. In the web part, click `Edit Snippet` and then add the following script references (make sure to you put in the locations to **your** script files):

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://yoursite/sites/yourlibrary/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://yoursite/sites/yourlibrary/StickyHeaders_v2.9BETA.js"></script>
   ```

EDIT: [Here's a source for referencing scripts](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp) -- see the section titled "Attribute Values" to see if that helps you understand how to reference your script files.

6. Save the Script Editor Web Part and the page. On the web part, click `Insert` to save the script references. Then click the `Save` button in the right-hand corner on the page to save the page.

Comment: OK. I am currently trying this out.

Comment: I'm not sure where I'm messing up. Which jQuery do I choose from the download page. There are many of them.

Comment: Do I have to save to a particular location?

Comment: Could "The publisher of StickyHeaders_v2.9BETA.js couldn't be verified. Are you sure you want to run the program?" message every time I try to download the scripts be a problem?

Comment: @Andrew For jQuery, download the compressed, production version (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js). For the Sticky Headers, you just want to download the file, but not run it http://spoodoo.com/download/javascripts/stickyheaders/StickyHeaders_v2.9BETA.js. 

Upload files to a library that's in the same site as your list. It can be in any library, but if you can, create a new Asset Library (instructions with images for how to do that are here http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2013/02/21/how-to-use-asset-library-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx).

Comment: Another question. Do I copy paste the entire URL shortcut in place of the words "location-of-your-script-file" only?

Comment: Also, isn't an asset library for images, audio, and video?

Comment: I updated my answer for how to reference the scripts. In SharePoint 2010, an Asset Library is a common place to store Javascript files, but in SharePoint 2013 this may not be the case. If anything, you can just create a standard library (or use an existing library) to store your Javascript files. Basically, you just need to store the Javascript files in a place where they won't get deleted/moved by other users because these files are what's making the sticky headers for your list. That's why it's not a bad idea to just setup a library that just holds Javascript files.

Comment: Got it. The only thing I can think of that is preventing this from working is the file type I'm downloading and uploading the script as? I don't know. I'm uploading the script to the SP library as a notepad document.

Comment: Make sure the scripts in your library end in `.js`. Just use Notepad to temporary store the shortcuts to the files so you can copy and paste them into the Script Editor Web Part.

Comment: If I go to rename, it shows a locked in .js after the text box. I feel like the only remaining problem could be where I save the scripts to on my computer before uploading them to the SP library, or the site administrator disabled this type of editing ability.

Comment: Now it's working, but only when I'm in edit page mode!

Comment: Let's move this conversation over to a chat so we don't have too many comments on this answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27475/discussion-between-clk-and-andrew).

Comment: Thanks for this post! I followed the steps you mentioned and it did work. But I have one problem. Only the current view of the list has the sticky headers. None of the others views have it. Do I have to repeat the same process for each and every view? Is there way to do it for all views at one go?

Comment: @Yashna07 I believe you will need to add the script to each view because each view is technically a different page/file.

Answer (score 1):

This is a awesome script !!!
It Works fine on SharePoint online !

Just added css style to make anchors visible.

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-spGrid-HeaderContentStyle a {
    color: #000000 !important;
}
</style>
```

Thank you very much. You made my day !

Answer (score 0):

We can make sticky headers work in SharePoint online site which is with New experience setting.

1. change list setting from New experience to default setting.
2. click on edit page, add script editor webpart.
3. click on Add snippet, Add below code:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://yoursite/sites/yourlibrary/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://yoursite/sites/yourlibrary/StickyHeaders_v2.9BETA.js"></script>`
   ```
4. click on stop editing, then you can observe that sticky headers work in 3 settings of a list: Default,New experience and classic.

**Note**: Make sure that you have added script files in given paths.

Comment: Add script files jquery.min.js and StickyHeaders_v2.9BETA.js