# SharePoint 2013 list with fixed header

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

Does anyone know? SharePoint 2013 list with fixed header? The request is to keep the header through the list fields.

Comment: There is already a same question here.  You can refer that https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/154313/how-to-make-a-custom-list-have-sticky-floating-headers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a custom solution called **StickyHeaders for SharePoint** which does what you have requested. It can be downloaded from here: http://spoodoo.com/sticky-headers-in-sharepoint-2013/. (I'll be only providing a link since the code is more lengthy.)

Generally you could just have a `fixed` position for the header row, but I believe that a) there are exceptions where such a quick fix will cause issues, and b) it's ugly.